# Парсинг сайта с JS страницами с jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup, парсер

Вот делаю такую штуку, чтобы вытащить список участников...проблема в том, что страницы списка на сайте генерируются JS... Как в jsoup пробежаться по этим страницам, которых 71 штука? )

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements list = doc.getElementsByClass("name showframe");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).html() + " \n" + list.get(i).absUrl("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JSoup это парсер HTML, а не эмулятор браузера. Так что скорее всего никак. Для полноценной работы возьмите Selenium.

Comment: мне рассказали, про GET и POST...так вот пытаюсь сделать правильный POST, чтобы по страницам пройти..пока не выходит)

Comment: Автор, спасибо за решение! Пригодилось!

Comment: Maria, Welcome.. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вобщем вот так вышло...может пригодится кому.

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Participants.csv"), "windows-1251");
        final String colNames = "Name;Country;Address;Phone;Fax;Site;Descr";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(colNames + "\n");

        final String url = "http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";

        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
        Document document = response.parse();
        String viewState = encode(document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").attr("value"), "UTF-8");
        String eventTarget = encode("p$lt$ctl12$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$UniPager$pagerElem" , "UTF-8");

        for (int i = 1; i <=71 ; i++) {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                    .requestBody(
                            String.format(
                                    "__EVENTTARGET=%s" + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=%d" + "&__VIEWSTATE=%s",
                                    eventTarget, i , viewState ))
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .post();

            Elements subList = document.getElementsByClass("name showframe");
            for (int j = 0; j < subList.size(); j++) {
                Document compPage = Jsoup.connect(subList.get(j).absUrl("href")).post();
                Elements compPageData = compPage.getElementsByClass("name");

                builder.append(subList.get(j).html().replace(';',',') + ";");
//                System.out.println(subList.get(j).html().replace(';',',') + ";");
                builder.append(subList.get(j).siblingElements().first().text()+ ";");
//                System.out.println(subList.get(j).siblingElements().first().text()+ ";");

                for (int k = 0; k <compPageData.size() ; k++) {
                    builder.append(compPageData.get(k).siblingElements().text().replace(';', ',') + ";");
//                    System.out.print(compPageData.get(k).siblingElements().text().replace(';', ',') + ";");
                }
                builder.append('\n');
            }
        }
        pw.write(builder.toString());
        pw.close();
    }
}
```